# Is there a way of solving activee x error

Tags: javascript, activex

I have a below piece of code which is working only with IE because of active X parser and I need to run it in chrome and other latest browsers.

```
< script language = "jscript" type = "text/javascript" > 
 function Transform1() { 
   var xml1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
   xml1.async = false; xml1.load(frmSoap.TestXml.value);
   frmSoap.Body.value = xml1.xml; 
 } 
< /script>
```

I tried to fix it by using the below change but it did not work for me and instead stopped working in ie as well.

```
function Transform1()

  if (window.DOMParser) { 
   var parser, xml1; 
   parser = new DOMParser(); 
   xml1 = parser.parseFromString(frmSoap.TestXml.value,"text/xml");
   frmSoap.Body.value = xml1.xml; 
  } else { 
   var xml1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.>XMLDOM"); 
   xml1.async = false; 
   xml1.load(frmSoap.TestXml.value);
   frmSoap.Body.value = xml1.xml; 
  }
```

Can somebody help me fix this issue.

Comment: `("Microsoft.>XMLDOM");`

Comment: This: _**I need to run it in chrome and other latest browsers**_ won't happen as ActiveX is a Microsoft IE extension only. Not even supported by Edge or latest IE versions anymore as IE 10 and 11 both filter out ActiveX by default. Some other browsers could use an NPAPI from Netscape, but it is also no longer supported either. Time to move into the 21st century.

Comment: @Randy Casburn - Thanks for your insight in the 21st century. I know that Active X is not supported and that is why I am using DOM parser to make it compatible. But this fix is not working and that is my query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that will work for you in all browsers. This is through the use of `createDocument()` and then having the browser parse the XML for you.

Please refer to the comments in the code.

```js
//Mock
const frmSoap = {
  TestXml: {
    value: `<productListing title="ABC Products"> 
  <product> 
    <name>Product One</name> 
    <description>Product One is an exciting new widget that will 
      simplify your life.</description> 
    <cost>$19.95</cost> 
    <shipping>$2.95</shipping> 
  </product>
  </productListing>`
  }
}
// Create an XHTML document
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'xhtml', null);
// Add body
var body = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);
// Parse the XML document and place it in the new XML doc body
body.innerHTML = frmSoap.TestXml.value;
//Parse the XML to produce output
const title = body.querySelector('productListing').getAttribute('title');
const productName = body.querySelector("product name").textContent;
const productDescription = body.querySelector("product description").textContent;
//Use the XML data
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `<h1>${title}</h1><span>Product Name:</span> ${productName}, <br><span>Product Description:</span> ${productDescription}`;
// Remove the doc when no longer needed
doc = null;
```

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is not solving my problem. I tried this but not working.

Comment: </script>

<script language="jscript" type="text/javascript">
function Transform1()
{
if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{
  var xml1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xml1.async = false;
  xml1.load(frmSoap.TestXml.value);

  frmSoap.Body.value = xml1.xml;
}
else if (window.DOMParser)
{ 
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xml1 = parser.parseFromString(frmSoap.TestXml.value,"text/xml");
  frmSoap.Body.value = xml1.xml;
} 
else
{
//Cant load XML
}
}
</script>

Comment: This is the change I did to make it work but after this change it has stopped working in both Chrome and IE.